# React external link

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, external

So I want to have external link in my react project and since I am new to programing I just noticed that  or  wont help me with that problem.

I have tried:

```
<Link to="google.com">
    Google
</Link>

<a href="google.com" target="_blank">
    Google
</a>
```

and both do the same - http://localhost:3000/google.com
And I want http://www.google.com.

Comment: The link is working as defined, but the URL isn't what you intended.  The browser has no reason to assume that `google.com` is anything other than a relative path in your application.  To redirect the user to another server, you need to prepend the `//` (or even the full `http://` if you like): `<a href="//google.com" target="_blank">`

Comment: Yeah thats why i deleted my comment Thanks @David